# Use Django forms/models to update multiple database rows

Tags: python, django

need to use django to manage some application specific database settings. I'm running into difficulty (I believe!) because of the underlying database structure. Unfortunately - this is pre-existing, and not able to be changed.

Essentially, I want to allow a user to select an option in a drop down box. This option will map to one or more rows in the database table, so:

User sees a drop down box pertaining to one 'ID' (in this example 2) that contains

Flavour:
 - Chocolate
 - Strawberry (initial selection)
 - Cheese

But at the backend, the change is to a table structured as follows:

```
table: FOOD_CONFIG
ID (non-unique) | parameter  | value  |
1               | Colour     | Brown  |
1               | Feel       | Sticky |
2               | Colour     | Red    |
2               | Feel       | Sticky |
```

When the user sets Cheese, it would change for the ID so that the table becomes:

```
ID (non-unique) | parameter  | value  |
1               | Colour     | Brown  |
1               | Feel       | Sticky |
2               | Colour     | Yellow |
2               | Feel       | Solid |
```

As an additional layer of complexity, based upon whether a Food has certain parameters, I'd like to dynamically generate the fields on the form. (so perhaps an odour selector would appear if the food ID has a 'pungency' parameter.)

I'm having trouble understanding the correct tool for the job.

The issue (as I see it) is that a Model looks like:

```
class FoodConfigTable(models.Model):
    ID = models.ForeignKey(FoodType)
    parameter = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'food_config_table'
```

and creating a ModelForm from it would allow the end user to modify parameter or value directly - not quite what I need.

I'm struggling to identify the correct workflow however. Perhaps something like this?:

```
def flavour_selector_view(request, food_id):

    fct = FoodConfigTable()
    fct.objects.filter(ID=food_id)

    if request.method == 'POST":
        # Make the model update the db

    # Create the dynamic form - can't fill out during construction as fields are created dynamically later (???)
    fcf = FoodConfigurationForm()
    fields = fct.get_fields_for_id(food_id)             #{'Flavour', 'Odour', ... , etc}        

    for f in fields:
        choices = fct.get_choices_for_field(food_id, f)  #[(1, 'chocolate'), (2, 'strawberry'), ... , etc]
        if f in request.POST:
            value = request.POST[f]
        else:
            value = fct.get_current_field_value(f)   
        fcf[f] = forms.ChoiceField(choices = choices, initial = value)

    render_to_response('flavour_selector.html', {'food_configuration_form': fcf})
```

After typing it all out, I feel I'm on the right track, but not having a solid grounding in Django makes me concious I'm missing either an obvious method, or poor or dangerous practice...

It's worth mentioning python version is 2.5, and django 1.0.2

(edit: minor typo fix on the ChoiceField creation)

Comment: an aside: why still using django `1.0`?

Comment: In short: Legacy support - existing hardware install base uses v1.0, and the software update mechanism wouldn't deal gracefully with the update (if I even had time to tackle that side of things!)

Answer (score 0):

I don;t know if this works in `django 1.0`. Look into django's `get_or_create` method for Models and try and use that to simplify your code. I would personally do something like:

```
# After user has made selection etc.
color, _ = FoodConfigTable.get_or_create(
           id=userid, parameter='Colour', value=flavor.color)
feel, _ = FoodConfigTable.get_or_create(
           id=userid, parameter='Feel', value=flavor.feel)
```

since every user seems to only have a single selection